# Wie sagt man Weltanschauung auf Französisch? / Comment traduire l'allemand “Weltanschauung”?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot, allemand, philosophie

Versteht man „Weltanschauung” auf Französisch, oder muß man etwas anderes sagen? Ich finde das Wort in Wörterbüchern (z.B. [Wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Weltanschauung)), aber ich weiß nicht, ob die meisten Franzosen dieses Wort verstehen. Sollte ich „*vision du monde*” oder „*idéologie*” schreiben? Was ist der Unterschied zwischen „Weltanschauung”, „*vision du monde*” und „*idéologie*”?

---

Est-ce que *Weltanschauung* (en allemand dans le texte) serait compris en français, ou faut-il lui trouver un équivalent natif ? Je trouve le mot dans des dictionnaires (par exemple [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Weltanschauung)), mais je ne sais pas si le mot serait compris par la plupart des français. Vaut-il mieux que j'écrive « vision du monde » ou « idéologie » ? Quelle différence y a-t-il entre ces trois termes (*Weltanschauung*, *vision du monde*, *idéologie*) ?

Comment: This question is a test, of course. If we're going to accept English questions, why not German, Chinese, etc? I'd appreciate if someone could correct my rusty German, by the way.

Comment: Nothing to correct here - all fine ;)

Comment: I don't see any valid reason to refuse the question myself, but shoudln't me have the discussion on this on meta?

Comment: @Gilles Becuase a bunch of people committed to the site on the basis of its being an English+French Q&A site, and moreover, English is the *lingua franca* of the StackExchange Network.

Comment: Please debate on [this meta thread](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/92/may-i-ask-a-question-in-language-est-ce-que-je-peux-poser-une-question-dans-l). @Jez [It was planned from the start that sites in other languages could exist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/is-it-ok-to-have-non-english-question-and-answers-in-area-51/53004#53004).

Comment: http://www.linguee.fr/francais-allemand/search?query=Weltanschauung propose beaucoup de ***convictions***

Comment: @cl-r Effectivement mais c'est dans un contexte très précis (critères de discrimination sociale).

Comment: Intéressant : il est possible qu'on me l'ai cité lorsqu'on étudiait Nietzsche en prépa. Aujourd'hui il m'est parfaitement inaudible. Pour proposer une solution, il faudrait le contexte. Un moyen de respecter et le lecteur et l'auteur est de : - soit mettre le mot allemand dans le texte et une note en base de page ou dans un lexique de fin d'ouvrage, - soit mettre sa propre traduction pour la fluidité de la lecture, et de préciser la source allemande en bas de page, afin que les spécialistes n'aient pas de doute sur l'intention ou la référence de l'auteur. Cf. : les traductions du sanskrit.

Comment: Pour clarifier un peu plus ce terme, il est vulgarisé par le mot "worldview" en anglais. Mais on trouve également l'expression allemande dans des ouvrages philosophiques ou théologiques.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dieses Wort wird auch auf Französisch benutzt. Zum Beispiel [hier](http://gallica.bnf.fr/Search?ArianeWireIndex=index&p=1&lang=EN&q=Weltanschauung) und [hier](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weltanschauung).

---

Le mot Weltanschauung est utilisé en français.

Une [recherche sur Gallica](http://gallica.bnf.fr/Search?ArianeWireIndex=index&p=1&lang=EN&q=Weltanschauung) m'a permis de trouver par exemple cet extrait:

> [...] que toute la conception traditionnelle imposée par le
>   christianisme, des rapports sociaux, est aux prises avec une
>   Weltanschauung radicalement opposée ; le sens profond des combats
>   actuels, c'est [...]

La Wikipédia française a un article dédié au Weltanschauung, ce qui semble indiquer qu'il n'y a pas de mot "plus français" collant au concept:

http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weltanschauung

Bien sûr, c'est un concept académique pointu que peu de gens sont susceptibles de connaître en dehors des universités de philosophie. Mais ce n'est pas une raison valide pour forcer l'usage un terme moins précis comme "*idéologie*" ou "*vision du monde*". Ce serait comme demander à un agriculteur de dire seulement "engrais" parce que "phosphate diammonique" n'est pas compris par la plupart des français. Tout dépend à qui on s'adresse: à des spécialistes ou au public général.

Comment: Ich habe auf Pico della mirandola und seiner Weltanschauung in "De dignitas" gearbeitet. Ich habe jedes mal ein anderes Wort benutzt. Einige passen weil Pico einen komplexen System entwickelt hat, nicht wie Hitler zum Beispiel (Weltanschauung in Google führt zu Hitler). "Cosmogonie" "Vision du monde" "Système de pensée" (breiter), "conception du monde" (rationeller).

Answer (score 8):

Je n'ai jamais entendu le terme *Weltanschauung* utilisé en français, donc je pense qu'il est préférable d'utiliser une des deux traductions, soit *idéologie*, soit *vision du monde*.

[*Conviction* semble être aussi une traduction possible](http://www.mijnwoordenboek.nl/vertalen.php?woord=Weltanschauung&src=DE&des=FR), peut-être dans un contexte plus personnel (p.ex. *"Je ne mange pas de viande par conviction"*)

Comment: Cela dit, je n'ai probablement rien compris à la question :-)

Comment: Il y a deux parties en fait dans la question : est-ce que *Weltanschauung* serait compris (la question n'est pas parfaite parce que je n'ai pas précisé à quel public je m'adresse), et sinon quel terme employer (en particulier quelle est la différence entre les termes proposés par le dictionnaire).

Comment: Comme quoi je n'avais pas si mal compris... et je pense même avoir répondu à la première partie. J'aurais répondu à la deuxième si j'avais su quoi répondre.

Comment: [OK, je mords...] Je pense que tout philosophe particulièrement intéressé par le terme, aura tendance à l'utiliser "en allemand, dans le texte". C'est clairement le cas en anglais (où le mot fait même partie du vocabulaire semi-courant).

Comment: +1 pour « jamais entendu parler », même si c'est probablement faux, je l'ai sûrement déjà entendu à l'oral. Je n'aurais jamais compris dans un texte écrit, en tout cas.

Comment: Le mot "idéologie" est quand même très connoté (et très politique, plus que philosophique) en français.

Answer (score 5):

Dans un contexte universitaire uniquement, on utilisera en effet le terme allemand sans le traduire.

En revanche, dans d'autres contextes, on a en français des expressions qui correspondront souvent assez bien :

- *représentation|vision|conception du monde*
- *paradigme* (dans certains contextes, notamment techniques)
- *idéologie* (attention cependant, parfois inadapté car connotations assez fortes)
- *point de vue* ou *conviction* (quand la simplification du terme est acceptable)