# “Life attitude” in French

Tags: traduction, anglais, philosophie

This is a question that could make you link me to a dictionary, but I'm not sure if using “*la vie attitude*” is the proper way.
I'm looking for a phrase that represents someone's attitude to life as of his philosophy. Actually, I'm trying to translate this:

> **Montaigne** has published his *Essais* explaining his philosohy and life attitude.

My solution:

> **Montaigne** creés son *Essais* expliquant son philosophie et son attitude de la vie.

Please note that my English is not perfect as well, so I may be a bit wrong with the usage of *attitude*.

Comment: Ce n'est certainement pas « attitude de la vie » ni « la vie attitude » qui ne sont pas franchement compréhensibles. Ça ressemble un peu à [Weltanschauung](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/290/wie-sagt-man-weltanschauung-auf-franzosisch-comment-traduire-lallemand-welt) mais il y a quand même une nuance.

Comment: Si _l'attitude de la vie_ sonne vraiment mal, il me semble que _l'attitude de vie_ pourrait passer dans une conversation française ?

Comment: attitude to/towards life ;)

Comment: agree with Lucas. life attitude sounds like life coaching. attitude to or towards life is much BETTER. Personne a vu que cela ne marche pas en anglais?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pour reprendre l'excellent commentaire de Gilles, les deux expressions proposées (*sa vie attitude* et *son attitude de la vie*) sont un peu artificielles et ne correspondent à aucun usage établi, elles sont maladroites et seront probablement mal comprises.

Dans d'autres contextes, on pourrait proposer **philosophie de vie** pour *life attitude*, mais l'utilisation présente (avec le terme *philosophie* utilisé dans la même phrase) rend ce choix impossible (ou très maladroit).

En plus des propositions de Gilles et cl-r, on aurait peut-être aussi **style de vie**, voire **éthique**.

Comment: *Philosophie* et *éthique* dans une même phrase, tautologie? *L'éthique* s'appliquerait plus aux principes de vie d'un Jansénisme dogmatique, qu'au simple *art de vivre* que toute personne construit selon sa sensibilité ; et pour lequel Montaigne a été un grand précurseur.

Comment: C'est un sens très réduit et spécifique que tu donnes à *éthique*, mais effectivement je ne l'avais cité que comme un usage plus discutable (*voire*) donc je peux comprendre la divergence de connotation que nous avons sur le terme. J'entendais 'ce qui nous détermine dans nos actions, notre conception du bien et du mal, sans prétention à l'universalité comme le serait une morale'.

Comment: ...ah oui aussi : *éthique* et *philosophie* n'ont pas du tout le même sens. Ou vois-tu une tautologie ?

Comment: *éthique* : science de la morale, art de diriger la conduite - *philosophie* : toute connaissance par la raison (opposé à *poésie* et à *histoire*) - *art* : ensemble de moyens, de procédés qui tendent à une fin ; les deux premiers sont liés à la pensée et au mental intégrés dans un groupe (ici l'art de diriger, donc d'imposer une volonté est celui de l'artisan, un art technique), le dernier est lié à la sensibilité et au corps en mouvement d'un être unique par essence (ici l'art est émotionnel, car il s'agit de la vie que l'on ne peut définir avec des mots qui ne peuvent que suggérer).

Comment: Vous volez trop haut là, à mon avis.

Comment: On parle aussi de mode de vie parfois.

Answer (score 3):

> Montaigne a publié ses *Essais* expliquant sa philosophie et son mode de
>   vie (ou son style de vie)

pour une traduction rapide,

> Au travers de ses *Essais*, Montaigne nous parle de philosophie et d'art
>   de vivre

pour une traduction plus littéraire.

Comment: "Art de vivre", mais pas "mode de vie".

Comment: @Rabskatran http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_de_vie donne une définition de base pour *mode de vie*, et la proximité de *style de vie* avec l'anglais lifestyle.

Answer (score 2):

Pardon, mais pour moi attitude to life, c'est son **attitude à l'égard de la vie**.

1) Ne nous enlève pas la Renaissance ! Nous ne pouvons nous en passer. Elle est devenue pour nous l'expression d'une attitude à l'égard de la vie. [...] C'est une conception de la vie, un soutien et un bâton de voyage pour l'humanité, et pas seulement un terme technique à l'usage de l'historien.
(Jan Huizinga)

http://crdp.ac-bordeaux.fr/cddp64/chateau/Valises_P%E9dagogiques/Renaissance.pdf

2) Tout devient objet de « pédagogie ». Le moindre comportement, la plus petite attitude à l’égard de la vie se trouve pris dans l’engrenage su « mieux-savoir-faire » auquel s’attache une kyrielle de pseudo-spécialistes plus ou moins patentés et formés. Réné Barbier

http://www.barbier-rd.nom.fr/INNOVATION.novation-CIRPP.htm

Une attitude n'est pas une philosophie. C'est autre chose. Et puis c'est très simple comme expression.

Answer (score 1):

La formulation la plus correcte me paraît être celle-ci :

> Montaigne a publié *Les Essais* qui nous explique sa philosophie de vie.

Je remplacerais tout simplement les termes *philosophy* et *life attitude* par *philosophie de vie* (en français).

Comment: Mais il me semble que dans le sens de la phrase originale il y a bien deux choses distinctes. D'une part sa philosophie, qui est un travail, une production intellectuelle, un ensemble de travaux, et d'autre part son ... (c'est bien le terme que nous recherchons) attitude ou mode d'application de ses valeurs, en tous cas un comportement social, des faits, des déclarations, des réactions. Ce sont bien deux choses différentes, non ?

Comment: Pour moi, dans le sens de la phrase, on peut combiner les deux idées en une.

Comment: @Zistoloen  Pour une traduction linguistique, cela peut s'entendre, mais s'il s'agit de saisir Montaigne dans son entièreté, la philosophie de Montaigne est plus induite par son art de vivre, que sa vie n'a été commandée par des concepts philosophiques (ne serait-ce que par son opposition au jansénisme). Il s'agit de traduire l'existence d'une philosophie, juxtaposée à une perception de la vie, qui demeurent non miscibles. Intrinsèquement la vie déborde le cadre philosophique limité par la raison.

Comment: Il ne s'agit pas de saisir Montaigne. Il s'agit de traduire ce que quelqu'un a écrit à son sujet. Une philosophie de vie n'est pas ce que la personne a dit en anglais. Elle parle d'autre chose.